# Django reverse relationship in many-to-many field

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

how do i get gallery response like bellow. Now, galleryserializer returns response with  images array with ids only. I am not able to get details of images.

json response:

```
{
    "name": "New Gallery",
    "images": [
        {
             id: 1,
             image: 'url/path/to/image',
             alt_text: 'alt'
        },
        {
             id: 2,
             image: 'url/path/to/image1',
             alt_text: 'alt'
        },
    ]
}
```

My **models.py** file:

```
class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique_with='id')
    images = models.ManyToManyField(GalleryImage, related_name="galleryimages")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My **serializers.py** file:

```
class GalleryImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GalleryImage
        exclude = '__all__'

class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested serialization

```
class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = GalleryImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Now i got error. **The  exclude option must be a list or tuple. Got str.**

Comment: change `exclude = '__all__'` to `fields = '__all__'`